# Does the higher-level testing mentioned in the book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" belong to integration tests?

Tags: testing, integration-tests

In the book *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* , there is section *Higher-Level Testing* in Chapter 2 Working with Feedback:

> Unit tests are great, but there is a place for *higher-level tests* , tests that cover scenarios and interactions in an application. Higher-level tests can be used to pin down behavior for a set of classes at a time. When you are able to do that, often you can write tests for the individual classes more easily.

Questions:

1. is *higher-level testing* a *standard* term in software engineering?
2. does *higher-level testing* belong to the *integration test* as it *pins down behavior for a set of classes*?

Answer (score 4):

> 1. is higher-level testing a standard term in software engineering?

No, I don't think so. It is just a description, which distinguishes those tests from unit tests in the specific context of the book chapter where you found it.

> 2. does higher-level testing belong to the integration test as it pins down behavior for a set of classes?

To my understanding, it is the other way round: the term "integration test", when used in opposition to unit tests, can be seen as one kind of "higher-level" tests (among other types of tests).